# Retrieve data from more than two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have five tables.

```
Employee(Fname,Lname,Empno(Primary),Bdate,Address,Salary,Dnumber(Foreign))
Department(Dname, Dnumber(Primary),Mgrno)
Location(Dnumber(Foreign),Dlocation)
Timesheet(Empno(foreign),Pnumber(Foreign),Hours_per_day)
Project(Pname,Pnumber(Primary),Location,Dnumber(Foreign))
```

How can I retrieve:

a. For project location 'ljk' list the project number, the controlling  Department and the Department Manager's `Fname`, `Lname` and `Address`.

b. Find the total salary of all employees in the 'F' department as well as the maximum, minimum and average of the salary in this department.

c. For each department, retrieve the Department number(Dnumber), the number of the employees and the average salary in the department.

For the problem c. I am able to retrieve data only about the the Department, Department number and number of employees. I am not sure how to add the average salary column in the result table.

For the other two part. I think it will need joining of more than 2 tables. But, I am not sure if that is possible.

sample:
Employee:

```
+-------+----------+-------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
| Fname | Lname    | Empno | Bdate      | Address | Salary | Dnumber |
+-------+----------+-------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
| g     | a        |   755 | 1986-09-09 | how     |   6598 |     100 |
| d     | v        |   796 | 1969-12-03 | e       |      2 |     101 |
| r     | n        |   850 | 1979-12-01 | a       |     10 |     100 |
| n     | h        |   879 | 1979-12-02 | b       |      8 |     101 |
| k     | k        |   888 | 1979-12-03 | c       |      6 |     102 |
+-------+----------+-------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Department:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Dname     | Dnumber | Mgrno |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| F         |     100 |   850 |
| ll        |     101 |   879 |
| M         |     102 |   888 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

Project:

```
+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| Pname    | Pnumber | Location | Dnumber |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| a        |      79 | ljk      |     101 |
| a        |      89 | ljk      |     100 |
| mardf    |      90 | kjk      |     102 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Timesheet:

```
+-------+---------+---------------+
| Empno | Pnumber | Hours_per_day |
+-------+---------+---------------+
|   850 |      89 |             6 |
|   888 |      90 |             6 |
|   879 |      79 |             9 |
+-------+---------+---------------+
```

Location:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Dnumber | Dlocation |
+---------+-----------+
|     100 | east      |
|     101 | west      |
|     102 | north     |
+---------+-----------+
```

What I have tried:

I have tried this for the part (c)

```
SELECT Department.Dname, 
    Department.Dnumber, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL EMPLOYEES' 
FROM Department 
INNER JOIN Employee 
    ON Department.Dnumber = Employee.Dnumber 
GROUP BY Department.Dnumber;
```

I am not sure how to add the average salary column here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a512f1

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
    Dname varchar(10),
    Dnumber int(5),
    Mgrno int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee(
    Fname varchar(20),
    Lname varchar(20),
    Empno int(5),
    Bdate date,
    Address varchar(10),
    Salary float(5),
    Dnumber int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Empno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
);


CREATE TABLE Location(
    Dnumber int(5),
    Dlocation varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dlocation),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Project(
    Pname varchar(10),
    Pnumber int(5),
    Location varchar(10),
    Dnumber int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Pnumber),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Timesheet(
    Empno int(5),
    Pnumber int(5),
    Hours_per_day int(5),
    FOREIGN KEY(Empno) REFERENCES Employee(Empno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Pnumber) REFERENCES Project(Pnumber)
);
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Good to add the example data, but you should also include the schemas of the tables (paste the create table statement for each table in your question). That shows us the column types and indexes for the tables.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I am new to Database Systems. It has been literally a month that we are starting DBMS in College. I am not understanding query enough to try those questions.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried already, even if it is just joining two of the tables.

Comment: While you are learning, a great tool to use is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Why did you remove your schemas and some of the sample data from your question? I was building a SQL Fiddle with all of the tables and sample data.

Comment: Because I wrote it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a512f1 @SloanThrasher

Comment: Still needs to be in your question. I've created a SQL Fiddle with the sample data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8571a0/0)

Comment: For problem C, look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfb0d8/6). It should give you a good start.

Comment: @SloanThrasher why are you using `Dname` instead of Dname ?

Comment: For problem a, what is the meaning of `For every project location 'a' ` as there is no project location data as `'a'`

Comment: @rgo: I've used backticks to quote schema objects like column and table names. Single and Double quotes should be used for string literals (IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these queries for all your particular problems.

And Here's the SQL Fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4ad1a/2/2

**For problem a:**

```
SELECT P.Pnumber as 'Project Number', 
D.Dname as Department,
E.Fname as 'Manager\'s Fname',
E.Lname as 'Manager\'s Lname',
E.Address as 'Manager\'s Address'
FROM Project P 
INNER JOIN Department D ON P.Dnumber = D.Dnumber
INNER JOIN Employee E ON P.Dnumber = E.Dnumber
WHERE P.Location = 'ljk';
```

*Output:*

```
| Project Number | Department | Manager's Fname | Manager's Lname | Manager's Address |
|----------------|------------|-----------------|-----------------|-------------------|
|             79 |         ll |               d |               v |                 e |
|             79 |         ll |               n |               h |                 b |
|             89 |          F |               g |               a |               how |
|             89 |          F |               r |               n |                 a |
```

**For problem b:**

```
SELECT SUM(Salary) as 'Total Salary',
MAX(Salary) as 'Maximum Salary',
MIN(Salary) as 'Minimum Salary',
AVG(Salary) as 'Average Salary'
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Department D ON E.Dnumber = D.Dnumber
WHERE D.Dname = 'F';
```

*Output:*

```
| Total Salary | Maximum Salary | Minimum Salary | Average Salary |
|--------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
|         6608 |           6598 |             10 |           3304 |
```

**For problem c:**

```
SELECT D.Dname as 'Department Name',
D.Dnumber as 'Department Number',
COUNT(DISTINCT E.Empno) as 'No. of Employees',
AVG(E.salary) as 'Average Salary'
FROM Department D
INNER JOIN Employee E ON D.Dnumber = E.Dnumber
GROUP BY D.Dnumber;
```

*Output*

```
| Department Name | Department Number | No. of Employees | Average Salary |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------|----------------|
|               F |               100 |                2 |           3304 |
|              ll |               101 |                2 |              5 |
|               M |               102 |                1 |              6 |
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started on problem **C**:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfb0d8/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
    Dname varchar(10),
    Dnumber int(5),
    Mgrno int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dnumber)
    );

CREATE TABLE Employee(
    Fname varchar(20),
    Lname varchar(20),
    Empno int(5),
    Bdate date,
    Address varchar(10),
    Salary float(5),
    Dnumber int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Empno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
    );


CREATE TABLE Location(
    Dnumber int(5),
    Dlocation varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dlocation),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
    );

CREATE TABLE Project(
    Pname varchar(10),
    Pnumber int(5),
    Location varchar(10),
    Dnumber int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY(Pnumber),
    FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES Department(Dnumber)
    );

CREATE TABLE Timesheet(
    Empno int(5),
    Pnumber int(5),
    Hours_per_day int(5),
    FOREIGN KEY(Empno) REFERENCES Employee(Empno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Pnumber) REFERENCES Project(Pnumber)
    );

INSERT INTO `Department`
(`Dname`,`Dnumber`,`Mgrno`)
VALUES
('Dept1','100','850'),
('Dept2','101','879'),
('Dept3','102','888');

INSERT INTO `Project`
(`Pname`,`Pnumber`,`Location`,`Dnumber`)
VALUES
('adfdd','79','ljk','101'),
('ffff','89','jkj','100'),
('mardf','90','kjk','102');

INSERT INTO `Employee`
(`Fname`,`Lname`,`Empno`,`Bdate`,`Address`,`Salary`,`Dnumber`)
VALUES
('g','a','755','1986-09-09','how','6598','100'),
('d','v','796','1969-12-03','e','2','101'),
('r','n','850','1979-12-01','a','10','100'),
('n','h','879','1979-12-02','b','8','101'),
('k','k','888','1979-12-03','c','6','102');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  a.`Dname`, 
  a.`Dnumber`, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.`Empno`) AS `TOTAL EMPLOYEES`,
  AVG(b.`Salary`) as `Average Salary`,
  MIN(b.`Salary`) as `Minimum Salary`,
  MAX(b.`Salary`) as `Maximum Salary`
FROM `Department` a
LEFT JOIN `Employee` b
  ON a.`Dnumber` = b.`Dnumber`
GROUP BY a.Dnumber
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfb0d8/6/0)**:

```
| Dname | Dnumber | TOTAL EMPLOYEES | Average Salary | Minimum Salary | Maximum Salary |
|-------|---------|-----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
| Dept1 |     100 |               2 |           3304 |             10 |           6598 |
| Dept2 |     101 |               2 |              5 |              2 |              8 |
| Dept3 |     102 |               1 |              6 |              6 |              6 |
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `Inner Join` ?

Comment: In case you need to get other values from the other tables. It started out getting values from several tables, and I removed that to fit problem C